# retrieve links from web page using python and BeautifulSoup than select 3 link and run it 4 times

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

Here is code.

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags

tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print tag.get('href', None)
```

There are 18 links. Now need to get position 3 means third link from the output and provide that link as input to html and run it again and do it 4 times. and what ever the last output at the position 3 than print out the name.

[https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html][1]

which will return 18 links from the above HTML. Now we need to select the 3 link and provide that 3rd link as an input to 'url' and follow the above loop for 4 times and what ever the last links comes out than get a name like in the first link 'fikret' is the name and what ever in the last link that is our output. Hope this helps. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Please add the page you are trying to scrape and what your expected output is.

Comment: Thank you 'dstudeba' for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish your homework in the following way (please take the time to learn this):

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# This function will get the Nth link object from the given url.
# To be safe you should make sure the nth link exists (I did not)
def getNthLink(url, n):
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    return tags[n-1]

url = "https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html"

# This iterates 4 times, each time grabbing the 3rd link object
# For convenience it prints the url each time.
for i in xrange(4):
    tag = getNthLink(url,3)
    url = tag.get('href')
    print url

# Finally after 4 times we grab the content from the last tag
print tag.contents[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much 'ajon'. It's working. I was stuck at after the output how would I get the 3rd link from output and provide that into the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do this is:

```
url = input('Enter url -')
count = int(input('Enter count -'))
position = int(input('Enter position-'))

for i in range(count):
   html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
   tags = soup('a')
   tag = tags[position - 1]  #get the URL link from an array
   url = tag.get('href',None)
   print('Retrieving: ' + URL)


print(tag.contents[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python 3.5 so here's the adapted version (and w/o def functions):

```
import urllib
import bs4
import re

times = 7 #number of times to click url
line_numb = 18 #I'm converting to python count later
url = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Terri.html "

for _ in range(times):

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    tags = soup.find_all('a')
    url=tags[line_numb-1].get('href')

print (url)
name = re.findall('known_by_(.*).html',url)
print (name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import BeautifulSoup
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()       # To ignore SSL certificate Error
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE


url = input('Enter - ')

count=int(input('Enter count: '))

pos=int(input('Enter position: '))


i=1
while True:
   if i>count:                                 # to run the loop at specified no of times.
      break

   i=i+1

   html=urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()               #to open the url
   soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
   tags=soup('a')                                  #extracts list of anchor attributes
   url=tags[pos-1].get('href',None)                        #extract tag at specified position . Indexing of attributes start with zero therefore pos-1

   print (url)
```